# How can I use vagrant to install zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I have developed an application that has all following installed and used:
My application itself,
Zend Framework 2
Bootstrap
couple of js libraries
PHP
Mysql.

If I, as developer #1, use vagrant and puppet, and install all above on it. 
Then how easy it is for developer #2 to get the exact installation.
Is it something like, I send him the vagrant zip file, and he just unzip dose Vagrant up, and then he has it all working?

Answer (score 0):

I can propose two approaches:

1. Create package containing `Vagrantfile`, puppet scripts and all necessary files for deployment e.g binaries with you application, configuration files, templates etc...
2. Create you own vagrant box. You setup your virtual machine and create vagrant box. Tutorials: [1](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/building-a-vagrant-box), [2](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/boxes.html). Next you just provide box file with proper Vagrant file.